# Doubletap and slide/drag finger to zoom in/out

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiscrollview, zooming

If anyone came across the google maps app for iOS there is a great feature to zoom in/out with one finger:
Doubletap on the uiscrollview and then immediately slide finger up or down to zoom in/out. 
Does anyone know how this is achieved? Did google post any snippet of that?

Comment: No one came across that???

Comment: It seems no one )) great oportunity to be the 1st!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this functionality to [my UIScrollView category](https://github.com/bddckr/BDDRScrollViewAdditions).
The actual tap recognition is easy, calculating the "correct" (whatever feels "correct") `zoomScale` is the problem… If you think the category isn't handling this good enough, please don't hesitate to tell me and open a new issue on the github page.

Answer (score 2):

Use a UIPanGestureRecognizer to track the up/down drag.
To ensure it only gets triggered on a double-tap, give it a delegate that does the following:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer == yourZoomRecognizer {
        return touch.tapCount == 2
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Now handle the messages coming from the gesture-recogniser. You can derive a zoom scale like so:

```
let zoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.01        //Each point of pan zooms in or out by this much
var zoomScale: CGFloat = 1            //Dummy variable for example purposes.

@IBAction func handleZoomGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began {
        //Set initial translation to reflect the current zoomScale
        let logZoom = log(zoomScale) / log(zoomFactor)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: logZoom), in: sender.view)
    } else if sender.state == .changed {
        let logZoom = sender.translation(in: sender.view).y
        zoomScale = pow(zoomFactor, logZoom)
    }
}
```

This doesn't show actually setting the zoomScale on a scrollview, which is a bunch of extra code - you'll want to get the pan gesture's location and center the zoom around that. You'll also want to clamp the zoomScale, and maybe handle the zoom ending too.

Answer (score 0):

This sample uses regular zooming capabilities of UIScrollView, which contains UIImageView as subview. You can find the implementation of such zooming in MWPhotoBrowser library for example. _imageView, _doubleTapBeganPoint, _longPressBeganPoint, _minScale are your class (UIScrollView subclass) iVars. So begin with initialization:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* lpgs = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageLongPressed:)];
lpgs.minimumPressDuration = .2;
[self addGestureRecognizer:lpgs];
```

Standard zoom handler:

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return _imageView;
}
```

Using touchesBegan to catch double tap (UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't want to work with UILongPressGestureRecognizer in some reason):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSUInteger tapCount = touch.tapCount;
    switch (tapCount) {
        case 2:
            [self handleDoubleTapBegan:[touch locationInView:self.superview]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [[self nextResponder] touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)handleDoubleTapBegan:(CGPoint)touchPoint {

    _doubleTapBeganPoint = touchPoint;

    NSLog(@"image double tap began at location: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
}
```

Handle long press and using difference in Y coordinates to calculate zoom scale. _minScale stores your initial zoomScale so we can restore it.

```
- (void) imageLongPressed:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture {

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        self.maximumZoomScale = _maxScale * 2;
        self.minimumZoomScale = _minScale / 3;

        _longPressBeganPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.superview];

        [self setZoomScale:_minScale animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"image long press began at location: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(_longPressBeganPoint));
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint p = [gesture locationInView:self.superview];

        //NSLog(@"image long press changed at location: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(p));

        if (CGPointEqualToPoint(_longPressBeganPoint, _doubleTapBeganPoint))
        {
            _zoom = _minScale + (p.y - _longPressBeganPoint.y) / 100.0;

            NSLog(@"zoom scale: %f", _zoom);

            [self setZoomScale:_zoom animated:NO];
        }
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"image long press ended at location: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint([gesture locationInView:gesture.view]));

        if (self.zoomScale < _minScale)
        {
            [self setZoomScale:_minScale animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"min zoom scale: %f", _minScale);
        }
    }
}
```