# MKMapView one finger zoom in and out

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

Google Maps has had this for a while (double tap then hold and slide finger up or down to zoom in or out) but Apple is just adding it to their Apple Maps app in iOS 11.

It does not seem like they are going to add this to `MKMapView`, at least not in the current betas.

If Apple does not give `MKMapView` this functionality how would I do this using gestures? Has anyone else done this?

Answer (score -2):

This will help you to zoom out to world-view.

```
// step.1 create co-ordianate-span as follows
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta = 180, .longitudeDelta = 360};

// step.2 crate region as follows
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0000f, 0.0000f), span);

// step.3 zoom using region to map as follows
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Comment: I know how to zoom into an `MKMapView`. I guess my question really is how can I smoothly zoom in or out using a gesture to slide my finger up and down.

Comment: @NicHubbard You have to attach to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol and implement. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5089553/3694459) might help you.

Comment: This works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848897/doubletap-and-slide-drag-finger-to-zoom-in-out/47271219#47271219